# Disable/deactivate the Junit tenant in hybris

Tags: multi-tenant, slave, sap-commerce-cloud

Is it possible to deactivate a slave tenant in hybris? I see that during start-up, my server spends a lot of time loading contexts for the Junit tenant, so I wanted to deactivate it to see if the server would start up faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, you can set the property `installed.tenants` in the local.properties file. And the hybris server does start up faster.